# SQL filtering based on date

Tags: java, sql

Let's say I'm performing a SQL query from a Java program to get timestamps (stored as milliseconds) from a table of timestamps that occur within the last 10 days.

I can think of the following two ways to do this:

```
db.execSql("select * from timestamps where timestamp > (SELECT strftime('%s', 'now', '-10 days') * 1000)");
```

or

```
// First calculate in the number of milliseconds in Java
long t = System.currentTimeInMillis() - (10 * 86400000 /* millis in a day */);
db.execSql("select * from timestamps where timestamp > " + t);
```

Both get the job done and seem to be equivalent perf-wise when testing. Is one method preferred over the other? Does it matter? Is there an idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally prefer to use the second method: if you end up needing to change the number of days, or the date from which the ten-day window is calculated, it will probably be more straightforward, understandable and maintainable to handle that in Java.

Answer (score 2):

How important is exactness on the boundaries? The time as seen by the server could be different than the time on the Java VM by several hours (e.g. timezones). I would generally go with the server-time based one, but my usual application would want to use the start of day and not NOW() so that the "bucket-boundaries" don't slide.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have no conclusive tests to prove this and this is just conjecture, I think I'd want to compute it in the software (via Java) and put the "bottleneck" there. Although it may be the same performance-wise, I wouldn't want the DB to be doing unnecessary work if it doesn't have to.

My guess is that you may have many clients running the same piece of software, but they're probably all querying the same database. Therefore, I side with the latter example.